# cellForRowAtIndexPath ignores sections

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

in my UITableViewController I defined 3 sections. But if I want to access more sections in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method than the first one, this is ignored. For example, if I want to add a row in the second section. Does anyone have a solution to the problem?

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   return 3;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        ..
        return cell;
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        ..
        return cell;
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 2) {
        ..
        return cell;
    }
}
if (indexPath.section == 1) {
            UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:aufgabe];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:aufgabe];
    }
    [cell.textLabel setText:@"Test"];
    }
}
else if (indexPath.section == 2) {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:geraet];
    return cell;
}
   return nil;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Funny! I fixed it for myself. I had to fill the numberOfRowsInSection method.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   if (section == 0) {
       return 3;
   }
   if (section == 1) {
       return 5;
   }
   else {
       return 0;
   }
}
```